# Ошибка NoneType object

Tags: python

Выдаёт одинаковую ошибку в двух частях кода: "for i, num in enumerate(nums):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".

```
def check(nums, true_nums): #Сравнивает два числа и сообщает кол-во быков и коров
    bulls, cows = 0, 0
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num in true_nums:
            if nums[i] == true_nums[i]:
                bulls += 1
            else:
                cows += 1
    return bulls, cows

while True:
    print('=' * 15, 'Ход игрока', '=' * 15)
    print('Угадайте число компьютера')
    number = input_number()
    bulls, cows = check(number, enemy)
    print('Быки: ', bulls, 'Коровы: ', cows)
    if bulls == 4:
        print('Вы победили!')
        print('Компьютер загадал число: ', enemy)
        break
```

```
bulls, cows = check(number, enemy)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".
```

Такая же ошибка и тут. В чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ошибка в одном месте, но возникла в функции в `check` в строке `for i, num in enumerate(nums):`, а причина в том, что `nums` содержит `None`. А значит ваша функцию `input_number` вернула `None`

Comment: @gil9red nums имеет значение. Оно заполняется в другой функции пользователем

Comment: какое значение имеет `nums` ? `print(nums)`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос функцию `input_number`. Скорее всего она у вас ничего не возвращает (нет `return`), поэтому в `number` попадает `None`.